# D3.js Animate Labels with ease bounce or linear effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, d3.js, svg

I have to implement a pie chart like this link http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4341574 but with labels and lines till the centroid of the arc.

any idea how can i rotate the lines too

```
    polyline.transition().duration(1000)
      .attrTween("points", function(d){
                  this._current = this._current || d;
                  var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
                  this._current = interpolate(0);
                  return function(t) {
                    var d2 = interpolate(t);
                    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
                    pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
                    return [arc.centroid(d2), outerArc.centroid(d2), pos];
              };    
        });
```

Comment: Please share some code which you have already done.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0a74tz21/  Sagar pls check this fiddle

Comment: Its not working.even not getting your chart.can you please re-post with correction.

Comment: goo.gl/4PSis7 pls try this link

Comment: In your fiddle, I'm already seeing the lines and labels with linear animation whenever the randomize button is clicked, so I'm not sure what the exact problem is.

Comment: Hi @Max pls follow these steps

1. Refresh the page. then u will see the linear effect of the pie chart.
2. and u will notice that the arrow lines and the labels are not rotating with the linear effect of the pie chart they just appear directly so it should also rotate as per the pie chart on a page refresh.